# Issue with defining layout for registration page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a problem with changing default layout for devise registration page.
Path for controller:

```
controllers/backend/registrations_controller.rb
```

When I add this line: layout 'backend', after refreshing view I have a white page. In other pages it works without any issues.

```
class Backend::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      layout 'backend'
      # GET /resource/sign_up
      def new
        super
      end

      # POST /resource
      def create
        super
      end
    end
```

Path for backend layout:

```
views/layouts/backend.html.haml
```

How can I correctly change layout for registration page? I read this [How To: Create custom layouts](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts)

Update:
I inspected white page and I see that backend laoyut was loaded, but I don't have idea why nothing shows.

Logs:

```
10:35:58 web.1  |   Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.haml (1.6ms)
10:35:58 web.1  |   Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.haml within layouts/backend (272.1ms)
10:35:58 web.1  | Completed 200 OK in 962ms (Views: 933.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

Comment: Can you give logs, something like this `Rendered members/sessions/new.html.slim within layouts/application`

Comment: Did you forget the `yield` in the backend layout?

Comment: @ArtemBiserov I update post.

Comment: @guitarman no I don't forget to add yield. This layout works on other pages.

Comment: can you show us this layout?

Comment: Ok I resolved my problem. I have check statement, that layout was loaded where user is sign in. I add a line of code to new method something like this: @current_person = current_person, and it works.

Comment: There's really no reason to define a method that simply calls `super`. Just leave it undefined.